# Get the size of the parent LI inside an UL?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I modify the below code so that I get only the parent `li` within the first `ul` and then with another variable get the sub `li` of the given sub `ul`?

```js
 $(function () {
  var vULSize = $("ul li").size();
  console.log(vULSize);
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>First</li>
  <li>Second
   <ul>
    <li>Second Sub 1</li>
    <li>Second Sub 2</li>
   </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Third</li>
  <li>Third
   <ul>
    <li>Third Sub 1</li>
    <li>Third Sub 2</li>
   </ul>
  </li>
 </ul>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/0sp9pohr/

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the second part of your question. What does "then with another variable get the sub LI of the given sub UL"? Do you want to count them? Do you want to count per `li` or in total? Could give the correct output for the example you provided?

Comment: Well you need to make the selector more specific for the UL.  Than you can just use the Child selector.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/0sp9pohr/1/

Answer (score 2):

First you need to wrap it all in something, say for instance a div with the id `container`. Then you can do something like this:

```
var vULSize = $("#container > ul > li").length;
```

The [`>` selector](https://api.jquery.com/child-selector/) gives you only the direct descendants.

If you want to count the number of list elements one level down, this will give you an array with the result:

```
var counts = $("#container > ul > li").map(function() {
    return $(this).find("li").length                                       
}).get();
```

As pointed out in comments, you should use [`.length`](https://api.jquery.com/length/) instead of `.size()`.

Comment: Or the OP could simply give the outer `<ul>` a class or id to differentiate it from the nested `<ul>` elements.

Comment: The `.size()` method is deprecated as of jQuery 1.8. Use the `.length` property instead.

Answer (score 2):

You can ignore all `li`'s that are descendants of an `li` like

```js
$(function() {
  var vULSize = $("ul li:not(li li)").size();
  snippet.log(vULSize);
});
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>First</li>
  <li>Second
    <ul>
      <li>Second Sub 1</li>
      <li>Second Sub 2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Third</li>
  <li>Third
    <ul>
      <li>Third Sub 1</li>
      <li>Third Sub 2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```